# ASP.Net: UpdatePanel Postback File Attachments Issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, postback

Here's the simplified scenario:

I have a page with two sections:  a search section, and a results grid that contains a list.  The user checks a checkbox for each row in the results grid that they would like added to a zipfile, then clicks a button which posts back to another page that generates a zip file.

So we have:

```
[UpdatePanel1]
...Search Inputs...
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
[/UpdatePanel1]
[UpdatePanel2]
..Results Grid..
<asp:Button ID="btnZip" runat="server" Text="Zip" PostBackUrl="~/Zip.aspx"/>
[/UpdatePanel2]
```

Where the logic in Zip.aspx looks like this:

```
SearchPage previousPage = (SearchPage)PreviousPage;
List<Files> docs = previousPage.GetSelectedFiles();

...do logic...

Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", zipBytes.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.zip");
Response.BinaryWrite(zipBytes);
Response.End();
```

The page works correctly in that you can search, which populates the results grid correctly, and you can select whichever rows and hit the "Zip" button as many times as you want and it will work correctly every time.

However, if you've hit the "Zip" button at least once, and go back to the search criteria and hit "Search" again, it results in this javascript error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near 'PK'.
```

Looking at fiddler, it seems like the Search button is posting back to "Zip.aspx" instead of itself.  Is there a way I can work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looking at fiddler, it seems like the Search button is posting back to
>   "Zip.aspx" instead of itself. Is there a way I can work around this?

If that's the case, try adding an OnClientClick handler to the SearchButton and make sure that the form action is set to the Search page itself instead of Zip.aspx

Something like:

```
function CheckPostBackURL()
{
   document.getElementById('aspNetForm').action="Search.aspx";
}
```

I don't know if it will work but that's an idea.

Comment: Yep, the following line worked: btnSearch.Attributes["onclick"] = "document.forms[0].action='Search.aspx';" + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSearch, null);